# How to enforce sender address to be "logged-in-user@example.org" in Postfix?

Tags: linux, postfix, smtp-auth

I have set up a Postfix server with SMTP AUTH (STARTTLS on port 587). All my users are in the domain "example.org". I want to enforce the sender address to be "logged-in-user@example.org".

I learned that this can be achieved with the main.cf options

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_sender_login_mismatch, ...
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/smtpd_sender_login_maps
```

with a login_maps file like:

```
a@example.org a
b@example.org b
c@example.org c
...
```

(see also [Block sender address spoofing with SMPT AUTH](https://blog.felipe-alfaro.com/2006/02/19/block-sender-address-spoofing-with-smpt-auth/)), but this would mean I'll have to edit the login_maps file every time I have a new user. I don't need such a flexible mapping: It should always be "logged-in-user@example.org". Is there an easier option?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, check whether your installation of Postfix supports pcre by entering the command `postconf -m` and looking for a line with `pcre` in it. Once you have verified that you have pcre support, you can do as follows:

`/etc/postfix/login_maps.pcre`:

```
/^(.*)@example\.org$/   ${1}
```

In `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_sender_login_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/login_maps.pcre
```

This should work fine.

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: For Ubuntu users, you can get postfix pcre with `sudo apt-get install postfix-pcre`. Maybe this was obvious to most.

Comment: No way to omit the domain in the regex or reference `$myhostname` variable?. [Here](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps) you can see that Postfix is capable to search the lookup table by the user part of the email...

Comment: I believe you'll want to backslash-escape the '.' character in the domain name so it is interpreted as a literal match: /^(.*)@example\.org$/

Comment: Otherwise, this matches "test@exampleXorg" as well as "test@example.org", which may not be exactly the intended behavior.

Answer (score 9):

The regex mentioned in the other answer matches the user part of the email address (**logged-in-user**@example.org). Here is some additional information.

To use the full email address as username, use the following regex (for example in `/etc/postfix/login_map`):

```
/^(.*)$/   ${1}
```

This means that your username is always your full email address (**logged-in-user@example.org**) - no other existing username is allowed to send from that address - and you don't have to update an additional Postfix config file everytime you add a user.

This might be used on a server that has multiple domains configured. User **john.doe@example.com** is only allowed to send from that address but not from **john.doe@example.org** (different user and email, different person). The username **john.doe** would be ambiguous in this case.

Also, depending on your configuration, the smtpd_sender_login_maps setting, which has to point to this file, may be in the master.cf (instead of main.cf). The official [Dovecot documentation has the following example](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixAndDovecotSASL#Using_SASL_with_Postfix_submission_port) (if you're using SASL/submission):

```
submission inet n - n - - smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

In this example, the setting should be adjusted to point to the right file and use regex or (better) pcre as type. Especially if a file called "virtual" is already used for another purpose (for example for [virtual_alias_maps, as shown in an official Postfix example](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_mailbox)), another file should be used for the login mapping.

From:

```
smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

To:

```
smtpd_sender_login_maps=pcre:/etc/postfix/login_map
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use combination of regexp on the header as shown here: http://www.akadia.com/services/postfix_uce.html? Then you can combine with regexp like [*@example.org] to ensure only sender from example.org.

Comment: Let's assume, I can use "regexp:" here (?) How can I specify the regexp such, that user "a" can send as "a@example.org" but not as "b@example.org"?

Comment: @sonstabo it would be nice if you include the configuration sample