# How to restrict user from using different forged sender email in postfix?

Tags: centos, postfix

I am managing a mail server. The mail server is running with multiple domains configured. The problem is authenticated user can use any sender email ID and I need to prevent it. How can I do that?

Example: a sender with email `anything@example.com` is sending mail with sender email address as `anything@yahoo.com`

I need to prevent that.

Comment: In your example, are both example.com and yahoo.com domains configured for your mail server?
Are you talking about the envelope sender or the From: header in the message itself?

Answer (score 2):

You do this with the configuration option `smtpd_sender_login_maps`.

It requires the user has SASL authenticated.

> smtpd_sender_login_maps (default: empty)
>
> ```
> Optional lookup table with the SASL login names that own sender
> (MAIL FROM) addresses.
>
> Specify zero or more "type:table" lookup tables. With lookups
> from indexed files such as DB or DBM, or from networked tables 
> such as NIS, LDAP or SQL, the following search operations
> are done with a sender address of user@domain:
>
> 1) user@domain
>     This table lookup is always done and has the highest precedence. 
> 2) user
>     This table lookup is done only when the domain part of 
>     the sender address matches $myorigin, $mydestination, 
>     $inet_interfaces or $proxy_interfaces. 
> 3) @domain
>     This table lookup is done last and has the lowest precedence. 
>
> In all cases the result of table lookup must be either 
> "not found" or a list of SASL login names separated by 
> comma and/or whitespace.
> ```

Then you add a configuration option along with the above to the smtpd_sender_restrictions optoin such as;

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch
```

Comment: Where do i specify the sender addresses? Or it is set automatically?

Comment: Its added as a comma seperated list against the sasl username mappings.

Comment: Hi Mlfe, i am extremely sorry but i am newbie and this is getting hard for me. If you mention step by step to do that i can learn this wonderful solution.

Comment: Finally i got this. Here is the solution: http://serverfault.com/questions/318334/how-to-enforce-sender-address-to-be-logged-in-userexample-org-in-postfix

Answer (score 1):

This works with Postfix 2.1+ If not, **reject_sender_login_mismatch**

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_sender_login_mismatch
```

According to postfix [documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html)
**reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch** enforces [**reject_sender_login_mismatch**](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_sender_login_mismatch)

> **reject_sender_login_mismatch:** Reject the request when $smtpd_sender_login_maps specifies an owner for the MAIL FROM address, but the client is not (SASL) logged in as that MAIL FROM address owner; or when the client is (SASL) logged in, but the client login name doesn't own the MAIL FROM address according to $smtpd_sender_login_maps.