# How to prevent users sending mail as someone else?

Tags: postfix

I have postfix 2.x on Debian 8 setup. I modified main.cf to have `smtp_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, permit`

As of now, for a domain example.com, I can't send mail as user1@example.net but I can send mail as user2@example.com.

How can I restrict users from sending mail as someone else? I don't want `bob` to act as `mary`.

Comment: http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/318334/how-to-enforce-sender-address-to-be-logged-in-userexample-org-in-postfix

Answer (score 4):

By using SMTP authentication. This also means that you cannot accept mail "as is" even from your trusted networks. However, if mail is destined to the domains you serve, you cannot prevent users to send mail as someone else - this flaw is in design of SMTP.